# How to read data from firebase realtime database in java?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

im trying to read data from database:

```java
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
Toast.makeText(More.this, "User-done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
Toast.makeText(More.this, "User-startReading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: task.getResult().getChildren()) {
Log.e("firebase",String.valueOf(task.getException()));
User value = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
Toast.makeText(More.this, "User-loaded data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
PreferenceConfig.Ammos(getApplicationContext(), ammoInt);
```

I saw toast: "User-done", "User-startReading", but "User-loaded data" i didn`t saw, so i can`t take data from db.

I saw some troubles in run-log:
W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out: testtesttest(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false.

So i added in manifest.xml

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

But, nothing happened

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also indicate the exact data you want to read.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it according documentation ([here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=de#java_1)) and it works for me.

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query recentPostsQuery = database.child("users").child(currentUser.getUid());
    recentPostsQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot noteSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String parent = noteSnapshot.getKey(); //parent key            
            }             
        }
    });
```

Comment: what `String parent = noteSnapshot.getKey(); ` is doing?

Comment: taking my example, You will get the users entries of the firebase database

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'currentUser'
I make app for android version 5,  19 sdk

Comment: currentUser is the FirebaseUser you get with `FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();`